# PostGIS function st_makevalid crashes the PostgreSQL Server

Tags: postgis, postgresql

When I run my code running on PostGIS version 2.5, I don't get an error but when I run it on 3.1 it the server gives an error and enters the recovery mode every time.

```
pgadmin4 messages:(*"Connection to the server has been lost."*). 

postgresql log : "*WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT (*
```

I have installed PostgreSQL on a separate server. Here I also get an error that PostgreSQL crashes due to the PostGIS function (eg:`st_makevalid`). In my opinion, there is a problem arising from the PostGIS version.

Can you try the queries yourself by trying on PostGIS extension versions 3.1.0 to 2.5?

I think we can see if there is a general problem of PostGIS 3.1.0 version.

PostGIS 3.1.0 - Query that raised an error:

```
select st_makevalid(
        st_force2d(
            st_multi(
                st_buffer(st_setsrid(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geometry), 4326), 0)
            )
        )::geometry (multipolygon, 4326)
    )
from (
        select j->'geometry' as geometry
        from (
                select (
                        '{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[39.75359,37.23446],[39.75359,37.23449],[39.75359,37.23415],[39.75391,37.23409],[39.7539,37.2341],[39.75373,37.23413],[39.75359,37.23446]]]}}'::json
                    ) as j
            ) t1
    ) t1
```

PostGIS 3.1.0 - Query that works without any problem:

```
select st_makevalid(
        st_force2d(
            st_multi(
                st_buffer(st_setsrid(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geometry), 4326), 0)
            )
        )::geometry (multipolygon, 4326)
    )
from (
        select j->'geometry' as geometry
        from (
                select (
                        '{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[28.89686,41.00149],[28.89698,41.00147],[28.89704,41.00157],[28.89693,41.0016],[28.89686,41.00149]]]}}'::json
                    ) as j
            ) t1
    ) t1
```

Operating System: CentOS Linux 8
CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:8
Kernel: Linux 4.18.0-193.28.1.el8_2.x86_64
Architecture: x86-64

postgresql-13
extension : postgis vers. 3.1.0

Answer (score 1):

The query that raises an error contains invalid GeoJSON geometry. Programs should not crash and you may consider to create a PostGIS bug report. For making your query to run and give reasonably results it is better to fix the invalid geometry as soon as possible.

I could not test with PostGIS 3.1 but your SQL works for me with PostGIS 3.0. without crash. However, the result is just an empty geometry.

Versions:

```
"PostgreSQL 12.3, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit"
"PostGIS 3.0 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1"
```

Query:

```
select st_astext(st_makevalid(st_force2d(st_multi(st_buffer(st_setsrid(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geometry),4326),0)))::geometry (multipolygon,4326))) 
from (
    select  j->'geometry'  as geometry
    from    (
            select ('{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[39.75359,37.23446],[39.75359,37.23449],[39.75359,37.23415],
                    [39.75391,37.23409],[39.7539,37.2341],[39.75373,37.23413],[39.75359,37.23446]]]}
                    }'::json) as j
        )t1 
    ) t1
```

Result:

```
"MULTIPOLYGON EMPTY"
```

The reason for the empty geometry is that the GeoJSON geometry is not valid.

```
select st_isvalidreason(    
ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geometry))
from (
        select j->'geometry' as geometry
        from (
                select (
                        '{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[39.75359,37.23446],[39.75359,37.23449],[39.75359,37.23415],[39.75391,37.23409],[39.7539,37.2341],[39.75373,37.23413],[39.75359,37.23446]]]}}'::json
                    ) as j
            ) t1
    ) t1    

"Self-intersection[39.75359 37.23446]"
```

By adding another MakeValid to fix the invalid GeoJSON geometry before sending it to ST_Buffer and so on the SQL returns a multipolygon.

```
select st_astext(st_makevalid(
            st_force2d(
                st_multi(
                    st_buffer(st_setsrid(ST_MakeValid(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geometry)), 4326), 0)
                )
            )::geometry (multipolygon, 4326)
        ))
    from (
            select j->'geometry' as geometry
            from (
                    select (
                            '{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[39.75359,37.23446],[39.75359,37.23449],[39.75359,37.23415],[39.75391,37.23409],[39.7539,37.2341],[39.75373,37.23413],[39.75359,37.23446]]]}}'::json
                        ) as j
                ) t1
    ) t1

"MULTIPOLYGON(((39.75359 37.23446,39.75373 37.23413,39.7539 37.2341,39.75391 37.23409,39.75359 37.23415,39.75359 37.23446)))"
```

Comment: Better yet, just use the inner `ST_MakeValid` and drop the `buffer(0)` AND the outer `ST_MakeValid`.

Comment: This is definitely a bug though, and should be reported.